# MySQL REPLACE appears to corrupt data

Tags: mysql, corruption

For reference, this issue was posted on [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127740/moodle-1-9-replace-breaks-utf8-unicode-ci-strings/11140693#11140693) before coming here.

In MySQL I am running multiple `REPLACE` queries to update hardcoded URLs in a database. Queries look like this:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET some_column = REPLACE(some_column, 'some_url', 'another_url')
```

The update process goes through every table and every string-based column in the database and runs a query like the above to ensure all potential occurrences are updated.

The system on which this is run also maintains some user content in the database. This content, which is (as far as I can tell) supposed to be unaffected by the update, becomes corrupted:

```
Before: Welcome to Company’s Learning
After : Welcome to Companyâ€™s Learning
```

The corruption looks like a string that may contain a unicode character which is not replaced correctly during the `REPLACE` query.

All tables are `InnoDB`, and `utf8_unicode_ci`. The server runs MySQL 5.5.25, on IIS 7.5.

Any idea why this kind of corruption is taking place?

Comment: Can you show exact data (just one row) and exact query that exhibits this behaviour? You could add a `WHERE table_id = X` to not scan the entire table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not look like a corruption problem. It might be a collation issue, not with the database, but with the IIS 7 or Moodle.

You did not specify if MySQL was running in Linux or Windows, so here it goes:

I ran queries to unveil collations and character sets

For MySQL 5.5.12 running on a Windows 7 machine, I get this:

```
mysql> show variables like '%coll%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                           |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                          |
| character_set_connection | latin1                          |
| character_set_database   | latin1                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                          |
| character_set_results    | latin1                          |
| character_set_server     | latin1                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                            |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\MySQL_5.5.12\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

For MySQL 5.5.9 running in Linux, I get this:

```
mysql> show variables like '%coll%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (1.75 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (1.69 sec)

mysql>
```

You have to make sure your connector software's character set/collation settings match the database it is connecting to. If the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) ran on the DB Server, the REPLACE is a case-sensitive match. I could easily see a collation shift in the eyes of IIS or Moodle messing up a server-side string replace.

You may want to substitute this with doing a client side replace using [**PHP's str_replace**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Thanks for your response - this is extremely helpful. Based on the character set and collation comparisons between the current Windows based server, IIS and a MacOS box which I know behaves as it should, all signs point to IIS being the culprit.